# Symfony Add Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to add a bundle manually without composer but with out any success.

**Error**

> The autoloader expected class
>   "Destination\Content\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle" to be defined in
>   file "/src/\Destination\Content\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle.php"

My folder structure looks like the following.

```
src\
   Destination\
      Content\
         ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle.php
```

**My AppKernel**

```
$bundles = array(
            ....
            new Destination\Content\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
            ....
        );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the github : https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle/blob/master/LiuggioExcelBundle.php#L3, the namespace is `Liuggio\ExcelBundle` but it should be `Destination\Content\ExcelBundle`.

Have you edited this namespace ?